# SELECT from 2 differents tables

Tags: sql, select, request

I would like to select all possible brands for different products where the fk_category_id is for example equal to "2".

produits :

```
id  titre   fk_category_id   fk_marque_id  is_active  is_delete
1   Swoke        2               1            1           0
2   Café         2               2            1           0
3   Fraise       2               3            1           0
4   Fruits       2               4            1           0
```

manufacturers :

```
id  name
1   Swoke
2   Liqua
3   Alfaliquid
4   TJuice
5   otherBrands
```

I already tried a lot of things and for example this request :

```
SELECT m.name, m.id, p.fk_category_id
FROM produits p
  INNER JOIN manufacturers m
WHERE p.fk_category_id = 2
  AND p.is_active = 1
  AND p.fk_marque_id = m.id
  AND p.is_delete = 0;
```

But it doesn't works.

The expected result is :

result :

```
id  name
1   Swoke
2   Liqua
3   Alfaliquid
4   TJuice
```

It's the same as the table "manufacturers" but I have to sort by fk_category_id because I only want the brand with the fk_category = 2.

So if someone could explain me or help me to understand how to solve my "problem" ? Thanks you in advance, I continue my research by my side :).

If you need something else i can give you anything.

Comment: Doesn't work - how? I'd expect a syntax error (missing ON clause for the JOIN.)

Comment: Sample data is great, but can you also _specify_ the expected result?

Comment: I got an infinite loop when I start the request in PhpMyAdmin. There is no syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need to do is have a condition on your join, to say how the data from the 2 table should join together.

On the assumption that ***fk_marque_id*** is your reference in produits to an item in manufacturers (assumed from looking at your where clause), your sql could look like this:

```
SELECT 
    p.id, p.titre, m.name, m.id, p.fk_category_id
FROM 
    produits p
    INNER JOIN manufacturers m ON p.fk_marque_id = m.id
WHERE p.fk_category_id = 2
AND p.is_active = 1
AND p.is_delete = 0;
```

The naming convention of your fields in *produits* is a little weird however, if one of the the FK fields is a link to an ID in manufacturers.  You'd normally expect to see something like ***FK_manufacturers_Id*** so it's clear that this column is the reference to that field (Id) in that table (manufacturers)

Comment: Thanks you for your help. But when I try your request I don't got the expected result.
I got in every rows the same brand with the same id ..

Comment: @Nicolas That is to do with what your selecting.  Try selecting p.id, p.titre, m.name, m.id instead - Have updated my answer to reflect what I think you want.  In your original Sql, you are only selecting the "Name" and "Id" from manufacturers table, so when you run the sql, that is why you're seeing the same data over for all the rows

Comment: Yeah it  almost works I just add a GROUP BY m.name to get distinct brand. Thanks you !

Comment: @Nicolas - Adding a GROUP BY doesn't give you a distinct brand. It's used when you've got aggregates in your select (such as Max, Sum, Average). If you want only a certain brand, you should add another cluse in the where to filter out a specific ID (eg. **and m.id = 2** would only select products where the manufacturer ID is 2)

Comment: I wanted to display the brands with fk_category_id = 2. But to have only 1 time each mark and not several times

Comment: I made a DISTINCT to solve it. Thanks you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking to join products and manufacturers table where fk_category_id = 2, it can be done something like this

```
SELECT m.id, m.name
FROM manufacturers m
  INNER JOIN produits p 
ON m.id = p.fk_marque_id
WHERE p.fk_category_id = 2
AND p.is_active = 1
AND p.is_delete = 0;
```

Comment: It's almost that. I tried your request with my filters : 
 SELECT m.id, m.name, p.titre
FROM produits p
  INNER JOIN manufacturers m
ON p.fk_marque_id = m.id AND p.fk_category_id = 2 GROUP BY m.id;
But I got an infinite loop when I launch it .. ( sorry for the indentation )

Comment: @Nicolas, which columns relate products and manufacturer tables? Is it fk_marque_id and m_id?

Comment: Yes it's p.fk_marque_id  and m.id

Comment: @Nicolas, then this code should work

Comment: It's almost works, it's not the expected result because I got in every rows of the result, the same brand and the same id. Do you know why ?

Comment: It's fine I add a GROUP BY m.name to take distinct brand.